# Remove quotes (single/double) from key/value of a JSON string

Tags: php, regex, json

Sample Input String:

> {"14" Alloy Wheels (Set of 4)":"N/A","Engine":"CrDi","15" Alloy Wheels":"optional","Other":"16" Wheels"};

There are 4 possible cases:

> {"key"here":
>
> ,"Key"here":
>
> :"Value"here",
>
> :"Value"here"}

I need to get rid of the inverted commas in between keys and values, which is causing

> invalid json

when using `json_decode` in PHP.

One possible solution is using RegEx, but I am not able to formulate the above possible cases.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string. Embedded quotes are supposed to be escaped with backslash. If you create the JSON string properly, `json_decode()` should be able to parse it, and you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: When the quotes aren't escaped properly, the string is ambiguous. There's no reliable way to tell whether the keys end and the values start. You can't just look for `:` and `,` because those could be part of the key or value.

Comment: You shouldn't try to parse this, you should fix the code that's producing the bad JSON in the first place. It's probably creating the JSON by hand, instead of using a library function like `json_encode()` in PHP or `JSON.stringify()` in Javascript. That's a recipe for disaster unless the data is very simple.

Comment: I am receiving the above string from an API, which I am saving in my db. I can only decode it at my side. I tried exploding the string by : , and for each element, I am again exploding by ", if the array length is odd, that implies an extra ", which I am replacing, but it's a double loop process, not efficient enough.

Comment: "__I am receiving the above string from an API__" tell the api admin to fix it. What you're receiving __isn't__ valid json.

Comment: @anurag: Please check if this works for you: `(?<=[{,:])"([^",:{}]*)"([^",:{}]*)"` to replace with `"$1$2"`. See https://regex101.com/r/uC5yV2/1 and http://ideone.com/AxR2Zb

Comment: Thanks stribizhev, it's working. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing with your string and I came up with the following solution.

1. Set `json` formatting apart from the rest
2. Correct the keys and values
3. Restore `json` formatting

   ```
   function repairJson( $str) {
       $search = array( '":"', '","', '":{"', '"},"', '{"', '"}' );
       $replace = array("':'", "','", "':{'", "'},'", "{'", "'}" );
       // Distinct json default formatting
       $str = str_replace( $search, $replace, $str );
       // Find and replace all " that are not yet escaped
       $str = preg_replace( '/([^\\\])"/', '${1}\"', $str );
       // Restore json default formatting
       $str = str_replace( $replace, $search, $str );
       return $str;
   }
   ```